# How to add a class for ninja form field_table?

Tags: contact, plugin-ninja-forms

I use ninja forms for a registration of an event. In the success message and in the confirmation mail, I want to show all the data entered by the users.

Ninja form has an filter called `{fields_table}`. But, I dont know how to style this using css or in other words, can I add a css class for this filter? If yes, how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

There is a filter named `ninja_forms_action_email_message` that you could use to manipulate the email message body.

I never tried, in the end I preferred to avoid using `{fields_table}` as a whole and manually created the HTML + styling in the form settings by specifying each single field manually.